# JMeter run LoginThread then all threads concurrently

Tags: java, jmeter

I need to run one thread group first (login), then after the login is ok, run all other thread groups concurrently.

How do I configure JMeter to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) to perform your "Login" operation. The setUp Thread Group is being executed before other Thread Groups so you can use it for some pre-requisites operations.

To check whether login is successful or not you can use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) like:

- Add If Controller after the Login request
- Use `!${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` as the condition. This is a [pre-defined JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) holding previous sampler execution result
- Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) Sampler as a child of the If Controller and configure it to `Stop Test`